# ant build failed after 2 hours on a target, once the issue get fixed build should run from failed target without changing build default command

Tags: ant

I came with a situation that ant build failed after 2 hours on a target, once the issue get fixed build should run from failed target without changing build default command, it mean to say that to save 2 hours build process on entire build life cycle. How can we achieve this situation. Kindly help me.

Regards,
Sankar B.

Answer (score 1):

I'm interpreting your question to mean you want to start your build process from the one that failed, skipping the dependent targets.  You can't skip the dependent targets, that I know of.

You can try something like this.  For each target, create two targets.  One that actually does the work and one that calls the dependent targets.  In you case, you would want to run `someTaskImpl`.

```
<target name="someTask" depends="init">
    <antcall target="someTaskImpl" />
</target>

<target name="someTaskImpl">
    <!-- do stuff -->
</target>
```